# Distinguish between comparatif and superlatif

Tags: comparatifs, superlatifs

I don't understand how to make a distinction between comparatif and superlatif in this situation:

> 1. I have met her daughters yesterday. The youngest daughter is very pretty.
> 2. I have met two of her daughters yesterday. The younger daughter is very pretty.

In the first case I would say:

> La plus jeune fille est très jolie.

But then, what would you say in the second case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En français on emploie le superlatif dans les deux cas.

Mais il faut savoir qu'il y a un mot spécifique pour parler du plus jeune d'une fratrie (ce qui correspond à l'anglais *youngest*) ou de deux frères et soeurs (ce qui correspond à l'anglais *younger*):  cadet/cadette. On dirait donc :

> J'ai rencontré ses deux filles hier. La cadette est très jolie.
>
> J'ai rencontré ses filles hier. La cadette est très jolie.

C'est bien sûr possible d'employer un superlatif :

> J'ai rencontré ses deux filles hier. La plus jeune (Celle qui est la plus jeune) est très jolie.
>
> J'ai rencontré ses filles hier. La plus jeune (Celle qui est la plus jeune) est très jolie.

Pas besoin d'en dire plus vu que ce qui précède explique de qui il s'agit.

En l'absence de précision de la première phrase, on pourrait dire :

> La plus jeune de ses filles....
>
> La plus jeune de ses deux filles/de toutes....

---

French has a specific noun to name the younger or youngest brother(s) or sister(s). *Cadet* (fem.: *cadette*) and it will often replace the superlative. But it's not compulsory to use it.
In the two examples you give in your question context is enough and makes it unnecessary to give further details and the superlative can be used in the same way in both second sentences of your examples.

Without context to be more specific you can say:

> La plus jeune de ses filles....
>
> La plus jeune de ses deux filles....

Comment: The OP's second sentence implies to me that the pretty one is the younger/youngest of the two that he met, but that there are other daughters who he has not met and who might be even younger. Would "cadette" be appropriate in sentence 2, even if she might not be the youngest in the family, as long as she is the youngest of the two that he met?

Comment: « [Cadet](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cadet) » ne désigne pas toujours le plus jeune. Il peut désigner celui qui n’est pas l’aîné, en particulier le second d’une fratrie. « [Benjamin](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/benjamin) » est moins ambigu. En fait, si je devais distinguer « the younger » de « the youngest », j’emploierais explicitement « la cadette » pour le premier et « la benjamine » pour le second.

Comment: @PapaPoule *cadet* means either "the younger" (when there are more than two) or "the youngest" (when there are several of them) that's why I've used it in both OP's sentences. My point was to say that in OP's sentences since the first sentence is saying if there are two of more, it is not necessary to me more precise when using the superlative. But I f one feels the necessity to precise the usual way is to add something after *plus jeune* (*des deux* or  *de ses filles* *de tous* etc...)

Comment: @Amphiteóth Il n'y a pas besoin de préciser « des deux » si, comme dans les exemples donnés, on sait s'il s'agit de deux ou de plusieurs. Par contre, comme je le dis dans ma réponse, on précisera s'il peut y avoir ambiguïté. « Cadet » s'emploie juste à la place de *the younger* ou de *the youngest* au sein d'une fratrie, ça n'empêche pas de préciser quand c'est nécessaire, c'est pour ça que j'ai parlé du contexte.

Comment: @Édouard Très bien l'apport de benjamin ! Ça évite de devoir préciser quand on parle de **deux** frères ou soeurs  uniquement.  Je n'ai parlé que du mot *cadet* qui convient dans les deux cas présentés et aussi hors contexte. Et hors contexte (ce qui n'est pas le cas de la question posée par l'OP) il faut de toutes façon préciser s'il s'agit des deux ou de tous.

Comment: @Laure Merci. Inutile « la cadette des deux », et « la cadette des trois », que j'avais en tête, serait de plus erroné. En effet, dans le sens de _plus jeune_, au Trésor(B. 2. a + b), indépendamment de la fratrie, c'est toujours par rapport à une seule personne référence que la comparaison s'effectue. Inversement, si trois filles avaient été présentes, on ne pourrait donc parler de la « la cadette » autrement que de celle qui vient après l’aîné(e).

Answer (score 3):

I'd translate the former by:

> La fille la plus jeune est très jolie.

and the last one:

> La fille plus jeune est très jolie.